# How to display only future events in Content Query Web Part?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, content-query-web-part

I have content query web part for displaying the future events. But the web part is displaying the past events as well. For example, I had two events in March and 3 in April. It shows all five event. I want it to show only April events.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the web part properties for the filter settings. You can choose a date column and date filter criteria to apply to the content query web part. For example, you can configure a filter on an Announcements list for items created "greater than" today.

See more on standard filters [a similar thread on MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/00bacfc3-621e-4277-bfd3-9a130896bc2b).

If the field you want is not displayed in the filters list, download the .dwp file and modify it manually to add the field. MSDN has [a walkthrough of the specific steps required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Created and Modified are in the filter list but not some other time and date fields. For example, the start date and end date fields of a calendar list are supported by the content query web part when you manually edit the .dwp and add the fields in as described on MSDN.

Comment: There is no "Time and Date" column in the filter options.

Comment: What is your source list? A time and date column in the announcements list for example, is named created.

Comment: My source list is just a calender and we add events to it

Comment: Updated my answer for a calendar list. Created and Modified are in the filter list but not some other time and date fields. For example, the start date and end date fields of a calendar list are supported by the content query web part when you manual editing the .dwp and add the fields in as described on MSDN.

Comment: Today is not a valid value for the filter in SP13...

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb is it possible you're not using the Calendar list type?

Comment: @GravityM  did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: @TomResing I think you are alluding to using a DVWP instead of CQWP, is that the preferred approach?

Answer (score 0):

When I look into filter option it also shows this example in the explanatory text below the filter:
*To filter on a column based on the current date or the current user of the site, type [Today] or [Me] as the column value.*

Comment: and how would you filter TODAY and the future?

Comment: Can you edit the answer to make it more valid?

Comment: By using 'greater of equal to'. Apply this filter: "Show only the items when the following is true: --> Show the items when the column" now select your column title with contains dates. Then select "Is greater or equal to" --> type exactly this: [Today]